# Can I store HTML fragments in different files but access via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Not sure if I have phrased my question correctly but I shall try to explain clearer in the body of my question.

I am using ASP.NET C#.

I have a single WebForm page.

In this page, for example I have this:

```
<div id="page1" style="display:block">
    page 1 contents
    <a href='#' id="liPage1" onclick='Page2();'>Page2</a>
</div>

<div id="page2" style="display:block">
    page 2 contents
    <a href='#' id="liPage2" onclick='Page1();'>Page1</a>
</div>

<script>
  //this is just sudo code
  Page1 function will hide div page2 and show div page1
  Page2 function will hide div page1 and show div page2
</script>
```

Now I do not need any help with the script.

What I am asking is whether I can have the HTML for page1 in 1 file and the HTML for page2 in another file and load these HTML 'fragments' via client-side.

I can easily do this in server code by encapsulating the HTML in a user-control.
I want to know if I can do the same using client calls.  But I really do not want to 'write' the HTML within JavaScript code itself.

I am asking this because I intend to have quite a few pages and I want to render it all via client-coding rather than calling back to the server each time.  It is all a question of readability and management.

I was thinking along the lines like resource files but not sure how.

I hope this is all clear?

Comment: Take a look at jQuery, specifically the `.load()` method.

Comment: Have both forms on a the same page. If JavaScript is disabled or non-functional then at least the user will be able to complete both sections of the form. Relying heavily of JavaScript is not advisable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your thoughts. If javascript is disabled then the app would not work anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply do some ajax calls, and then set the response as the content of a container element.

So, let's say yo have file1.html, file2.html and file3.html, and you want to include all those "fragment files" in a #container.

The script will look something like this:

```
[
    "file1.html",
    "file2.html",
    "file3.html"
].forEach(function(file) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", file, true);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
        document.querySelector("#content").html += xhr.response;
    });
    xhr.send();
});
```

Comment: Hi,  thanks for your time but my question states that I do not want to make calls to the server.  But thanks

Comment: Sorry! I thought you wanted to do the same "include" things you do in server side, but in the client.

Then, the answer, afaik is no. If you want to have content in external files, you need ajax calls to get them. If you want to reduce the amount of calls you can implement something like application cache or local storage.

Comment: hi, not a problem.  glad for your time. However, it is possible to do what I want using the jQuery .load() method as provided by @MikeW above :)

Comment: jQuery.load() does an ajax request. Just check the log in the developer tools of your browser.